# Titanium pen writing

Tags: titanium, pen

Is there a way to allow people to handwrite on the tablet with a pen, and saving the writing somewhere (as image... or if I'm lucky, as a characters recognition and save the text)
All this in appcelerator titanium

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually [one of the first tutorials Appcelerator released](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2010/05/building-an-advanced-transaction-ui-with-titanium.html). They've released it as a module.